# How to enable RESTCONF server in IOS-XR?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-ios-xr, ios-xe

I aim to enable `RESTCONF` server on `Cisco IOS-XRv 9000`.

I did not find online anything about enabling `HTTP` server in this IOS-XR version. However, with `NETCONF` server can be enabled.

For `IOS-XE` is quite easy to enable `RESTCONF` where you use only

```
(config)# ip http server
(config)# restconf-yang
```

But in IOS-XR is not the same. Anyone can help :)

Comment: Last time i saw this enabled, you just had to write `RP/0/RP0/CPU0:router(config)# http server` without ip in front of it. Have you installed the Manageability package and activated it?

Comment: @Cown it does not work with `RP/0/RP0/CPU0:router(config)# http server`. 

For the Manageability package, I did not.

Comment: What happens when you write the command `http server`? What log is generated?

Comment: @Cown .`% Invalid input detected at '^' marker` Is it required to install Software Package Management Commands on the Cisco IOS XR Software in order to enable  `http server` ?

Comment: For the XML and HTTP host services, the Manageability package must be installed and activated on the router.

Comment: @Cown well, I'm quite beginner in this IOS XR software. I have found a lot of packages in here [link](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/crs/software/crs_r4-0/system_management/command/reference/yr40crs_chapter15.html)  which one must be installed ?

Comment: You can search for Manageability Package in the link you provided. It's not typically installed as default.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESTCONF is not supported on IOS-XR. Only NETCONF and gRPC.